# How do I use Java 6 when java 7 is installed?

Tags: java

How do I use Java 6 when I have both java 6 and java 7 installed? I need both.

Comment: Install Java 6?

Comment: When I run java -version I get "java version "1.7.0_79""

Comment: I have installed both java 7 and java 6. I'm asking how do I **use** java 6 when 7 is installed.

Comment: That wasn't clear, sorry. Run this: `sudo update-alternatives --config java`

Comment: That will change the default.

Comment: If you need only one program to use the java version, that has to be changed in the settings of that program, or by `/path/to/java6/java -jar program.jar`

Comment: Put that as an answer so I can give you credit.

Comment: Ok I found the path, and I'm making a batch file to run this one program that needs java 6 (it's the only one) Put your comments in an answer so I can give you credit for your help

Comment: Check `/usr/lib`. Which part should be the answer? Both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change your default version of Java, you can run

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

A prompt will come up, showing all versions of Java you have installed. Input the list number for the version you want to be the default.

If you want to run one program with a non-default Java version, you need to run the command

```
/path/to/java-install/java -jar /path/to/program.jar
```

This obviously only works with `.jar` files, so it might be best to have two scripts that can switch the default version.

Comment: It also provided me the locations of each java version so that I could make custom scripts, which is what I did.

Comment: Ah, that's great